# is it possible to use template in Kendo Combo box which is populated using knockout-kendo.js?

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

here's the combo box not using knockout-kendo,

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(x => x.TaxYear)
.Name("ddTaxYear")
.DataTextField("Year")
.DataValueField("InvestorVersionId")
.BindTo(Model.AvailableVersions)
.HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "input-small", maxLength = 125, @Id = "ddTaxYear" })
.Template("<span>#: data.Year # <i class='#: getIcon(data.InvestorVersionId) #'></i> </span>")
.Events(events => events.Change("onEffectiveYearChange")))
```

here's the new one that using knockout-kendo.js

```
<input data-bind="kendoComboBox: { dataTextField: 'Name', dataValueField: 'Id', data: taxYearList, value: taxYear }" />
```

but I cannot style it now. is it possible to add

```
.HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "input-small", maxLength = 125, @Id = "ddTaxYear" })
.Template("<span>#: data.Year # <i class='#: getIcon(data.InvestorVersionId) #'></i> </span>")
```

to kendoComboBox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Knockout-Kendo bindings will pass through any options that you give it on to the actual widget.

So, you can actually include a `template` option like:

```
<input data-bind="kendoComboBox: { dataTextField: 'name', dataValueField: 'id', 
    data: choices, value: selectedChoice, 
    template: '<span>Name: #: data.name # </span>' }" />
```

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/jgs9H/

Comment: thank you so much, i am surprised how easy it is to add a new option.